# Twilio get on-going call charges

Tags: twilio

How can I get/read ongoing call charges [which is in-progress] ?

The below code returns the current usage for the current date, but it is not returning accurate usage when call is in-progress or completed [It's taking around 2 minutes to return exact usage].

```cs
RecordResource usageRecord = (await RecordResource.ReadAsync(twilioSubAccount.SID,
                        category: RecordResource.CategoryEnum.Totalprice,
                        startDate: startDate,
                        client: twilioRestClient))
                        .FirstOrDefault();

string totalPrice = usageRecord.Price.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Usage records are not updated in real time. You can see that [usage records have an `asOf` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record#usagerecord-properties) that tells you the time they are accurate up to.

[Individual calls also have a `price` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-properties), but it is also only populated after the call is complete.

I don't think you can get absolutely up to date call charges, particularly for ongoing calls.